# Linux screen command not accepting keyboard input

Tags: serial-port, gnu-screen

I am trying to connect to a JTAG device using screen.

I type the command `sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB1 115200,cs8`

I am able to see all of the output from the board, but I am unable to type anything into it. I was previously able to do that just fine on this same board. Have I messed up some screen setting that is blocking my input? I do not believe it is a problem of just not echoing the input, because when I type Enter, the commands on the device do not get sent or execute.

OS is Ubuntu 19.10
5.3.0-42-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:49:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The JTAG device shows up in lsusb as:
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0403:6010 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C/D/H Dual UART/FIFO IC

Comment: I would check the connection cables.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kate said in comments, I would go step by step.

- As it seems FT2232C is on-board of JTAG adapter. So most probably no way to make hardware loop-back (UART 2 - 3 pins connected)
- See if you have stand-alone UART-USB cable, and make loop-back. If echo works than PC and its software (`screen`) side is fine.

To here, it's not Ubuntu issue anymore. Just hints to continue.

- This is a Dual UART, then it is possible they get enumerated differently. Check with 2nd serial port.
- Kits may easily get damaged. Check its developer site. If it has a DFU/Bootloader mode and if FW is good. May be it has a demo to check some functions like LED or GPIO control.

I just saw a deleted answer, kind remind: It is always good to power-off all devices and start experiment over, which will confirm if issue can reproduced.